# Django ORM not performing SELECT queries in testing

Tags: python, django, django-south

I'm experiencing an issue with the Django ORM in our current application after upgrading from Django 1.4 to Django 1.6 recently. This issue is *only* showing up while running tests, not while running in development or production environments.

More specifically, we have a `post_save` hook which collects information from tables which subclass our main data object and coalesce the data stored in those objects into a `SearchDocument` object which is then stored and queried in order to provide full-text searching on the interface. This works in both development and production environments, but when attempting to run unit tests, we have issues where tests are failing.

Our method, which is in the process of being debugged, looks something like this right now:

```
def _update_search_document( self, doc ):
    """Updates and saves an existing search document for this model.
    This will sync the search text and key/value attributes."""
    # A bunch of code updating the model properties prior to saving.
    doc.save()
    print SearchDocument.objects.all()
    print connection.queries:
```

This code saves correctly, but the subsequent call to `SearchDocument.objects.all()` returns `[]` and the `connection.queries` property contains the `INSERT` SQL from the `doc.save()` call but does **not** contain (at any point) `SELECT` SQL from any of the three extant `SearchDocument SELECT` queries which should have been performed to that point.

To the best of my knowledge, this code was working prior to our migration from Django 1.4 to Django 1.6. I know that some of the query logic changed between 1.4 and 1.6 and I'm wondering if there's a setting (perhaps surrounding caching?) that's causing problems with our tests now.

Edit: After a bit more hacking, I've been able to determine that moving this test class to a `SimpleTestCase` instead of the `TestCase` class which subclasses `TransactionalTestCase` (which wraps each test in a DB transaction) resolves the issue that I was seeing with items not showing up after they've been saved. It appears that something in that transaction management is causing the problems with the saving.

Comment: Django querysets are lazy. Try to iterate over the queryset and then check `connection.queries`, e.g. `for _ in SearchDocument.objects.all(): break`. Also, do you have `DEBUG` set to `True`?

Comment: Iterating over the queryset shows the same behavior (`print` should evaluate the queryset as well) and DEBUG is set to true. If it's set to false, none of the queries at all show up.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting my edit because this is how we eventually solved it:

> After a bit more hacking, I've been able to determine that moving this test class to a SimpleTestCase instead of the TestCase class which subclasses TransactionalTestCase (which wraps each test in a DB transaction) resolves the issue that I was seeing with items not showing up after they've been saved. It appears that something in that transaction management is causing the problems with the saving.